# How to assess if a distribution has significantly changed over time

Tags: hypothesis-testing, categorical-data, contingency-tables, frequency, discrete-distributions

I'm studying the incidence of different types of influenza in a country over several years. In particular, for years from 2015 to 2020 I know the relative abundance of 3 types of influenza (% of influenza A, of influenza B and of influenza C).

I want to assess if the relative abundance of these types has significantly changed in 2020.

Example:

|  | **2015** | **2016** | **2017** | **2018** | **2019** | **2020** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **A** | 0.29 | 0.35 | 0.31 | 0.41 | 0.28 | 0.15 |
| **B** | 0.41 | 0.32 | 0.27 | 0.28 | 0.32 | 0.07 |
| **C** | 0.3 | 0.33 | 0.42 | 0.31 | 0.4 | 0.78 |

From the table is clear that from 2015 to 2019 the 3 types of influenza have similar incidence and then in 2020 something happens and their relative abundance dramatically changes.

How can I assess if the distribution of the influenza types in 2020 is significantly different from the distributions of the years before?
Which statistical test should I use for this purpose?

Here my hypothesis is that the relative abundances observed for the years 2015-16-17-18-19 $\{a_{2015},a_{2016},a_{2017},a_{2018},a_{2019}\}$ are samples of the same unknown distribution $A$. And I want to test the following null hypothesis: *the relative abundance of the influenza types observed in 2020 is again a sample of the distribution $A$*.
Is there a test that allows me to accept/reject this null hypothesis?

Thanks to anyone who will be able to give me advice!

Comment: You can't test this hypothesis only with the statistics you have shown.  You need to take a step back and explain what *data* you have.  How exactly do you obtain these abundance values?

Comment: Thank @whuber for your comment. Well, for each year and for each influenza type I have a certain number of reported cases and from these values I compute the relative abundance of the types. However, I'm working with percentages and not with the absolute numbers of cases because I'm interested to see if the proportions for A,B and C change in 2020 rather than looking at if their absolute incidences increase/decrease.

Comment: You still need to work with the absolute numbers because they give you information the proportions do not: namely, about the *uncertainties* in those values.

Comment: Ok @whuber, thank you! And do you have any suggestion for a procedure that I could implement to test my null hypothesis?

Comment: Several procedures are in common use and are easy to carry out.  For instance, a $3\times 2$ table of the 2015-2019 *totals* and 2020 data (by types) summarizes the relevant information and can be tested with a chi-squared test.  But your question is a little suspicious, for two reasons.  First, it appears you formulated your hypothesis after examining the data: this renders all such calculations of significance invalid. Second, why are you not interested in learning about the trends throughout this period, rather than just in 2020?

Comment: 1) I formulated my hypothesis before examining data: in 2020 covid appeared and the incidence, the diffusion and the transmission of several respiratory diseases changed dramatically. So I suspect a change also for influenza. 2) it would be also fine to learn something about the trends, but still I have no idea of which analysis I should perform. I formulated my research question in terms of 'before 2020' and 'after 2020' because I wanted to define a clear null hypothesis to accept/reject with some statistical test

Comment: Those are good reasons to indicate you ought to compare pre-2020 data to post-2020 data.  *How* to do so depends on how you conceptualize and model the data, but in the end it won't matter: the difference is stark.  You scarcely need a formal test.  A chart will do.